# MvcSiteMapProvider Node URL rendered as /#

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

As the title states, the URL for one of the nodes in the breadcrumb is not correct. I just get a http://localhost/#

Obviously I have something wrong.
I have other, similar structures in the sitemap that are working. Can you tell from this whats missing?

I can post more info if needed.

SiteMap    :

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="ISP" controller="xxx" action="Index">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="PC" action="Details" preservedRouteParameters="pcId">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="SGD" controller="yyy" action="Details" preservedRouteParameters="pcId, yyyId, editable">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="ESGN" controller="yyy" action="Title" preservedRouteParameters="pcId, yyyId, editable" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Actions:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("xxx/{pcId:int}/yyy/{yyyId:int}/Details/{editable:bool}")]
    public virtual ActionResult Details(int pcId, int yyyId, bool editable)
    {


    [HttpGet]
    [Route("xxx/{pcId:int}/yyy/{yyyId:int}/Title")]
    public virtual ActionResult Title(int pcId, int yyyId)
    {
```

Route Map:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "xxx",
            url: "xxx/{action}/{pcId}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "xxx",
                action = "Index",
                pcId = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
            );
```

Update: When removing the "editable" parameter it started to work.
Could there be an issue with more than 2 params? or possibly the type or name of the parameter?

Update following debug advice from NightOwl88:

The urlHelper does generate the correct url's

This is my controller code:

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("TransactionDetails/File/{fileId:int}")]
    public virtual ActionResult Index(int fileId)
    {
        {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(new System.Web.Routing.RequestContext(this.HttpContext, this.RouteData));
            var url = urlHelper.Action("Index", "Transaction",
                new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary { { "id", 678 } });

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(url);
        }

        {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(new System.Web.Routing.RequestContext(this.HttpContext, this.RouteData));
            var url = urlHelper.Action("Index", "File",
                new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary {{"fileId", 123}});

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(url);
        }
```

I get:
/AdministratorConsole/TransactionDetails/678
and 
/AdministratorConsole/TransactionDetails/File/123

So the helper is able to generate a url for me but MvcSiteMapProvider is still not happy.

SiteMap is:

```
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Transaction Log" controller="TransactionLog" action="Index">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Transaction Details" controller="Transaction" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="id">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="File Details" controller="File" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="id, fileId"> <!--TODO link back to parent not working-->
```

Answer (score 0):

A `#` indicates the URL could not be resolved based on the information provided (between the current request and what is in the node configuration). See [Why does Default UrlResolver throw an exception](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/115) for an explanation.

`MvcSiteMapProvider` resolves the URL through MVC's `UrlHelper` class, so if you are having trouble, you should [use the `UrlHelper` explicitly](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Controlling-URL-Behavior#using-net-routing) to troubleshoot. If you put the below code into a controller and edit it to match the request that is generating a `#`, you will be able to determine how to resolve the URL correctly. However, unlike in `MvcSiteMapProvider`, the `UrlHelper` will return `null` if the URL cannot be resolved. The most likely reason is that you are missing a route value that you have set as *required* by the route.

```
// Using controller and action
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(new System.Web.Routing.RequestContext(this.HttpContext, this.RouteData));
var url = urlHelper.Action("View", "Videos", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary { { "id", 123 } });

// Using controller, action, and route name (similar to @Html.RouteLink())
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(new System.Web.Routing.RequestContext(this.HttpContext, this.RouteData));
var url = urlHelper.RouteUrl("RouteName", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Videos" }, { "action", "View" }, { "id", 123 } });
```

Comment: Thanks ill give it a try.  Interestingly the node that has the issue does get a good Url when its the last node in the list, but not when its the second to last.

Comment: I have updated my question. UrlHelper is generating a URL for me but MvcSiteMapProvider is not. Anything else I can try?